# Json Request URL with Base64 string

Tags: javascript, json, http, base64, todataurl

I have an image which `reader.readAsDataURL(file)` has encoded to base64 string.
I have also used 
    `var imageBlob = ImageDataUrl.substring(ImageDataUrl.indexOf(",") + 1);`
to strip out the `data:image/png;base64`, part.

now i have to send the base64 string via a json request using
`var link =  "http://localhost:9002/AppAPI/rest/app/uploadImage?image="+imageBlob;` .

But postman receives no response and my guess is that some characters from the base64 string affects the Http request URL.

Please is there any way i can work around this?

Comment: Try using POST instead of GET.

Comment: I have used POST and GET and both don't work

Comment: 1) base64 isn't optimal for sending data 2) you can use products like https://www.filestack.com/ to get image uploads out of your way 3) if you are worried about conflicting characters use ```encodeURIComponent```

Answer (score 0):

GET is definitely not the right method to use when uploading an image. GETs [must be both idempotent and safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) (i.e. repeatable and read-only with no side effects). In fact, RFC 7231 4.2.1 explicitly warns against safe methods performing actions with side-effects based on query string parameters:

> For example, it is
> common for Web-based content editing software to use actions within
> query parameters, such as "page?do=delete".  If the purpose of such a
> resource is to perform an unsafe action, then the resource owner MUST
> disable or disallow that action when it is accessed using a safe
> request method.

For an image upload, you probably want to do a PUT, with the image contents in the body of the request, not the query string (and therefore no need to base64 encode it). Placing the image contents in the query string is unlikely to work correctly. Most servers enforce a limit on URI length, which will almost certainly be exceeded by all but the smallest base64-encoded images. According to [RFC 7230 3.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1), the server *must* send a 414 response to the client when the URI is too long, though I wouldn't be surprised if there were non-compliant servers ignoring that requirement.

You may need to escape the = sign(s) at the end of your base64-encoded string, but I recommend scrapping the base64-encoded query string parameter entirely.